# How to safely make sure an async method in C# is completed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

please excuse the possibly stupid question. Is there a difference between the two code snippets?

Example 1: Running an async method CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync in a synchronous method

```
class Core
{
    async void ProcessCommand(Command cmd)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        await JobManager.ReportTrigger(cmd.TriggerID);
        SendCommand(Command reply);
    }
}

class JobManager
{
    async Task ReportTrigger(Int32 triggerID)
    {
        await Task.Delay(300);
        Webcam.CapturePhotoToFile();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}

class WebCam
{
    void CapturePhotoFile()
    {
        m_MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync( ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), file );
    }
}
```

Example 2: Running the async method CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync as a task:

```
class Core
{
    async void ProcessCommand(Command cmd)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        await JobManager.ReportTrigger(cmd.TriggerID);
        SendCommand(Command reply);
    }
}

class JobManager
{
    async Task ReportTrigger(Int32 triggerID)
    {
        await Task.Delay(300);
        await Webcam.CapturePhotoToFile();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}

class WebCam
{
    async Task CapturePhotoFile()
    {
        await m_MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync( ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), file );
    }
}
```

I really need to make sure that the Call "SendCommand(Command reply)" is being executed AFTER the webcam picture has been saved. Which method is more suitable for this purpose?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

**EDIT:**

According to the comments received i am currently thinking about this implementation:

```
class Core
{
    async Task ProcessCommandAsync(Command cmd)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        await JobManager.ReportTriggerAsync(cmd.TriggerID);
        SendCommand(Command reply);
    }
}

class JobManager
{
    async Task ReportTriggerAsync(Int32 triggerID)
    {
        await Task.Delay(300);
        await Webcam.CapturePhotoToFileAsync();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}

class WebCam
{
    async Task CapturePhotoFileAsync()
    {
        await m_MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync( ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), file );
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could ensure me the intended behaviour for this implementation. Is it really assured that the command in Core.ProcessCommandAsync is send AFTER the picture has been saved?

@Dai: Thanks for your feedback. I merged my answer into my first posting. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: You **cannot** safely call async code from a non-async call-site (with the exception of when there's an `async void` synchronization context, which is only the case in WPF and WinForms - in UWP you never need to have a non-async call-site). What is the context of this code?

Comment: "The await operator suspends evaluation of the enclosing async method until the asynchronous operation represented by its operand completes" from [await operator documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await). Meaning, if you `await` `JobManager.ReportTrigger` it will block until `JobManager.ReportTrigger` finishes

Comment: 2nd version is more correct. The `await` in `await Webcam.CapturePhotoToFile();` + the `await` inside the inner method makes sure it is completed before executing the next line.

Comment: @Pac0: So the second example is the way to go in order to ensure my photo is saved before JobManager.Reporttrigger returns and the command in Core.cs will be send?

Comment: @Pac0 Not necessarily, You'll run into problems if you use `await` inside an `async void`  method in a Console program or Windows Service, for example.

Comment: @Roland If a method returns a `Task<T>` then it should be named `FooAsync` - your `CapturePhotoToFile` method is not named `CapturePhotoToFileAsync` so it isn't immediately obvious to callers if it's meant to be `awaited` or not.

Comment: This code is part of an UWP application, but i did not get it: What is the problem with async void? Should i convert the ProcessComand from async void ProcessCommand to async Task ProcessCommand?

This method is being called from a background thread as soon as the software received a message from the ethernet interface.

Comment: @Roland **Never use** `async void` for a method declaration **ever** application because there's no way for any continuations inside to be sure to run (the only exceptions are async event-handlers in WinForms and WPF). Always use `async Task`or `async Task<T>` for your method's signatures.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few rules that make async easier to get right.

1. Async functions return Task or Task<> (don't use void)
2. Async functions are named with Async on the end (MyFuncAsync) - this reminds you to call await on those functions, see rule 3.
3. Await any async functions (unless you want them to run in parallel)
4. Don't break these rules.

Keeping to these rules can be hard, if you have already broken them, and have to refactor your program.

(there are lots of exceptions to these rules, but if you don't know what you are doing, then try to keep to the rules).

Comment: Can you explain rule 4 please?

Comment: I'd clarify point 3 by saying that the `Task<T>` that is returned from an async function **must** be awaited *eventually*. So it's better phrased as: "Never discard or ignore an async function's `Task` return value".

Comment: Just an addition: Since C# 7.0 async methods can return any object that provides a public `GetAwaiter` method. `ValueTask<TResult>` (integrated in .NET Core 2.0 and available via the NuGet package System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions otherwise) is an example utilising this new feature.

Comment: All of these are bad rules.  Anyone writing lots of asynchronous code should be breaking all of these rules fairly frequently.  Also, none of this answers the question asked.

Comment: @Servy Just imagine you are a beginner with async, and not the expert you obviously are.  If I was reviewing a beginners code and 1 or 2 came up, I would be asking why they broke those rules. 3 is slightly more advanced, but 90% of the time is still correct.

Comment: @Neil When someone's new it's all the more important to not tell them things that are false and that will build bad habits and improper understandings of the tools that they're using.  Telling someone to never do something that they should be doing 10% of the time is going to cause major problems very early on for them.  Especially when you use super hard wording making it clear that you think they should *never* do things it will cause tons of confusion in that 10% of occasions where that's what they should be doing.